Cannot compare passwords using Bcrypt checkpassword in Delphi
Using Delphi Seattle10. Downloaded BCrypt from github https://github.com/JackTrapper/bcrypt-for-delphi
I have read all the posts regarding bcrypt and delphi. I am able to hash and store the password but not able to compare the stored password to what the user enters at login.
Here is my code:
  uses Bcrypt;

  Proc createuser;    
  var
   Pswd, StoredHash : string;   
  begin
   Pswd := RZEdit1.text;
   StoredHash := CreateHashedPassword('Pswd');
   table.edit;
   table.field := StoredHash;
   table.post;    
  end;


  Proc VerifyUserpassword;
  var
   VerifyPswd, StoredHash, hashedpassword : string;
   isPasswordValid : boolean;
  begin
   VerifyPswd := RZEdit1.text;
   StoredHash := Table.field
   isPasswordValid := True;

   (*try 1*)
   --------
   if isPasswordValid = TBCrypt.CheckPassword(VerifyPswd , StoredHash, 
                            {out}PasswordRehashNeeded) then
        TzDialogBox('Password', 'P', 'Password is valid.', '');

   (*try 2*)
    --------
    HashedPassword := TBCrypt.EnhancedHashPassword(VerifyPswd , salt, 12);
     if  storedhash = HashedPassword then
           TzDialogBox('Password', 'P', 'Password is valid.', '');                
end;

Appreciate the help!
Thanks

I successfully use code like your try 1 with MySQL and it works. Are you sure that your database is configured to use BCrypted password hashes?

What is the text value of your RZEdit1? In your createuser procedure you are creating and then storing a hash for a "Pswd" password instead of Text value that is in your RZEdit1. So unless the Text value of your RZEdit1 is "Pswd" at verification time the hashes should not match.

@fpiette - yes, thanks you.

@SilverWarior - while creating the user (newuserfrm)  I'm storing the RZedit1.text in Pswd and then hashing it assigning that hashed value to stored hash which I later store in a table. I retrieve the stored hash and use that to verify what the user entered in RZEdit1 (LoginFrm). Thank you

I had to download a diff version of the BCrypt and the code works now.

What does that mean: "a diff version"? A specific commit/branch to which you could have linked?

@msgopala CreateHashedPassword('Pswd') is hashing the string literal 'Pswd'. You need to drop the quotes in order to hash the text in your Pswd variable, eg:  CreateHashedPassword(Pswd). Also, it would help to see how CreateHashedPassword() is implemented to know if your BCrypt logic even matches it.

@AmigoJack I dont recollect the url for the pas file. There are minor changes in code like below
`class function TBCrypt.Prehash256(const password: UnicodeString): string;
var
key: TBytes;
procedure BurnArray(var AArray: TBytes);
begin
if Length(AArray) > 0 then
begin
ZeroMemory(@AArray[0], Length(AArray));
SetLength(AArray, 0);
end;
end;
begin
key := TBCrypt.PasswordStringPrep(password);
try
Result := TBCrypt.HashBytes(key, 'SHA256');
finally
BurnArray(key);
end;
end; `

@RemyLebeau typo. It was as you mentioned, without quotes.
